# Add detail text on label of custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

There are other similar questions here but none of those answer what I'm looking for.

I have a settings screen that should look like this:

[image]

I have added new `UITableViewCell` class and connected it to main table with this code:

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"settingCellIdentifier";
SettingsTableViewCell *cell = (SettingsTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil){

    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SettingsTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

I know we set table style to UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle to add detail text, but the only way I know to do that is this:

```
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
            initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
            reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];
```

I can't use this code in my case.

Currently I'm using two labels, and it has brought the following mess:

[image]

Following is cellForRowAtIndexPath code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"settingCellIdentifier";
SettingsTableViewCell *cell = (SettingsTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil){

    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SettingsTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}

NSInteger row = indexPath.row;


switch (row) {
    case 0:
        cell.settingLabel.text = @"Settings"; 
        cell.subText.text = @"";
        break;
    case 1:
        cell.settingLabel.text = @"Account Info";
        cell.subText.text = @"Display your Home Business account information";
        break;
    case 2:
        cell.settingLabel.text = @"Sign Out";
        cell.subText.text = @"Signed in as ";
        break;
    case 3:
        cell.settingLabel.text = @"Send Feedback";
        cell.subText.text = @"Send comments, requests or error reports to Home Business";
        break;
    case 4:
        cell.settingLabel.text = @"Terms of User";
        cell.subText.text = @"";
        break;
    case 5:
        cell.settingLabel.text = @"Privacy Policy";
        cell.subText.text = @"Your privacy and security are our top priorities";
        break;
    case 6:
        cell.settingLabel.text = @"Like us on Facebook";
        cell.subText.text = @"";
        break;
    case 7:
        cell.settingLabel.text = @"Follow us on Twitter";
        cell.subText.text = @""; 
        break;
    case 8:
        cell.settingLabel.text = @"About Us";
        cell.subText.text = @"";
        break;

    default:
        break;
}

return cell;
}
```

I need to know how I can add detail text with only one label.

Comment: go for  custom table view cell , why you have any specific need ?

Comment: Show the code where you are populating labels.

Comment: i AM using custom table view cell. Need to know how i can add detail text for label there.

Comment: @FawadMasud: cell.settingLabel.text = @"Account Info";

            cell.subText.text = @"Display your Home Business account information"

in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Are you using auto layout? And if so are your constraints properly set?

Comment: yes I did "add missing constraints". But what I really need is to know how i can add detail text under the label.

Comment: Please post your entire cellForRowAtIndexPath method

Comment: i've added complete code.

Comment: Sometimes, "add missing constraints" doesn't give you what you want. You should add the constraints you need explicitly.

Comment: BTW, you don't need a custom cell if all you're doing is adding a main text and a detail text; just use a UITableViewCell, and set its type to "subtitle" in IB.

Comment: i understand. But that is not my need. I need detail text with only one label.

Comment: Why do you need to use only one label?

Comment: no i need to use custom cell for further functionalities. Plz help here

Comment: a label has the property of detail text. I need to use that one. But to do that I need to set table style to UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle. I need to know how i can do that

Comment: @TahreemIqbal The problem lies in your custom SettingsTableViewCell class... You'll need to post that code too.

Comment: That's not a table style, that's a cell type.

Comment: @LyndseyScott there's nothing there. Only two outlets of two labels

Comment: @TahreemIqbal Then why do you need a custom view? In any case, your labels don't seem to be laid out correctly in your interface and are overlapping when they shouldn't. If you want to use the table view's inherent label and detail label, this issue can automatically be avoided.

Comment: alright.. guess I could try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need a custom cell? Just use normal tableview cell and its textLabel & detailTextLabel. This will serve your need. You can even set the number of line for detailTextLabel. Try this:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Profile";
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vix id debet libris. Quem oblique blandit ne vix, repudiare prodesset an mel. At libris tacimates accusata has, eum at ignota cotidieque. Pro malorum nominati ei.";
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 1){
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Server";
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vix id debet libris. Quem oblique blandit ne vix, repudiare prodesset an mel. At libris tacimates accusata has, eum at ignota cotidieque. Pro malorum nominati ei.";
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 2){
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Security";
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vix id debet libris. Quem oblique blandit ne vix, repudiare prodesset an mel. At libris tacimates accusata has, eum at ignota cotidieque. Pro malorum nominati ei.";
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 3){
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Forget Password";
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vix id debet libris. Quem oblique blandit ne vix, repudiare prodesset an mel. At libris tacimates accusata has, eum at ignota cotidieque. Pro malorum nominati ei.";
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 4){
        cell.textLabel.text = @"About";
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vix id debet libris. Quem oblique blandit ne vix, repudiare prodesset an mel. At libris tacimates accusata has, eum at ignota cotidieque. Pro malorum nominati ei.";
    }
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    return cell;
```

Comment: that's what everyone has suggested and so I've done it this way. Thank you.